# flex output not showing correct behavior

Tags: flex-lexer

I am in a compiler design course and have to learn flex for lexical analysis. Now, as much as I have understood, flex matches the characters from input stream with the translation rules and gives output accordingly.
So, the following code should output a string of "character" equal to length of "hello world" - 1. But its printing "goodbye" instead. Have I understood something wrong here?

Code :

```
%%
[a-zA-Z]          printf("character");
"hello world"     printf("goodbye");
%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lexer doesn't recognize whitespaces so it uses the rule with the specified string. Insert this rule:

```
[ \t\n\r] printf("%s", yytext);
```

However, according to the [documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Flex-is-not-matching-my-patterns-in-the-same-order-that-I-defined-them_002e.html), it will resolve the ambiguity with the longest match which is still the "goodbye" rule.

Comment: @darthvader: It prints 'goodbye' because it's the only rule which matches 'hello world'. The first rule matches only characters. Try the rule I wrote in the answer. This should work.

Comment: well, its still printing goodbye for hello world. here is what I've got uptil now:%%
 [a-zA-Z\s]+   printf("character");
 [ \t\n\r]         printf("%s", yytext)   ;
"hello world"   printf("goodbye");
%%

Comment: @darthvader: Remove '\s' and '+' from the first rule. Just [a-zA-Z] as origin.

Comment: What if you remove the goodbye rule? Is it printing 'character'?

Comment: Nothing, just confusion! :P However, it will use the 'string' rule because in an ambiguous flex program it will choose the rule which matches the longest string.

Comment: is there some reference for that? Because my professor just gave a breif explanation about how the first translation rule found will be used.This video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54bo1qaHAfk also says the same thing

Comment: [Here.](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Flex-is-not-matching-my-patterns-in-the-same-order-that-I-defined-them_002e.html)

Comment: @darthvader He's wrong. It picks the longest match.